# Validation range in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, range

I get stuck on laravel. My goal is to create a validation rule to forbid values between 5000 and 7000.
I've tested a lot of things like `not_in:range(8000,9000)`but I didn't make it. Anyone have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom validation rule as mentioned in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
Validator::extend('no_in_range', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return (($value < 5000) && ($value > 7000)) ? true : false;
});
```

I have not tested this code but this is what you are looking for. Please make adjustments as per your need.

Then you can just use `no_in_range` as other validation methods.

```
'field' => 'no_in_range'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'field' => 'between:5000,7000'
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom validator and check if the number is within this range, then add error to the validator. You can use Laravel Request.